# How to get the convergence by interpolation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence

Assume that $u_n$ converges weakly to $u_*$ in $H^1(\mathbb R^n)$, and $U$ is a positive function such that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
|U(x)|\le Ce^{-|x|}.
$$
Then, if $1<p<\frac{n+4}{n}$, how to show
$$
\int U^{p-1} u_n^2 \to  \int U^{p-1}u^2_*\quad?
$$
I am not sure whether the $p$ is important for this question.
By following [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_inequality), you'll see what I found about interpolation in Wikipedia: but I feel it is useless to my purpose.

**What I tried**.  By applying Holder and Sobolev inequalities, I get the following inequality
$$
\left|\int U^{p-1}u_n^2\right|\le C \|\nabla u_n\|
$$
but this is seemingly useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Rellich-Kondrachov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem) Theorem the map $H^1(B_R) \to L^2(B_R)$ is compact, where $B_R$ is a ball of radius $R$. Then $\{\varphi u_n\}$ converges strongly to $\varphi u_*$ in $L^2$, where $\varphi$ is a cut-off of $B_R$.

Since $U^{p-1}$ is bounded, we get the inequalities
$$
\int U^{p-1}\varphi^2(u_n^2-u_*^2) \le \lVert U\rVert^{p-1}_\infty\lVert \varphi(u_n+u_*)\rVert_2\lVert\varphi(u_n-u_*)\rVert_2 \to 0.
$$
We use the decay of $U^{p-1}$ to control the unbounded region outside the support of $\varphi$, so
$$
\int U^{p-1}(1-\varphi^2)(u_n^2-u_*^2) \le Ce^{-R}(\lVert u_n\rVert_2^2+\lVert u_*\rVert_2^2).
$$
If we take $R\gg 1$, then we conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int U^{p-1}(u_n^2-u_*^2) < \varepsilon,
$$
for every $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks very much.